# What is the Islamic way to counter Sihr (magic)?

Tags: nikah, sihr

I suspect somebody has cast evil spill on my son and his wife. Although they married out of their own willingness, their marriage is in tatters 1 year into their marriage. My son apparently didn't have sex with her for months and treated her very badly. She says she no longer loves him and doesn't want to see his face. Our family is close to collapse, is there an Islamic way to find out if sihr is involved? And how can I find a Muslim scholar to help us. I just don't want to get involved with people involved in satanic rituals who work under the guise of Islamic scholars.

*Please help my family*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let’s pay heed to the verse 102 Surah al-Baqara which indicates that Sihr (magic) could be a cause of separation between a man and his wife.

> وَاتَّبَعُوا مَا تَتْلُو الشَّيَاطِينُ عَلَىٰ مُلْكِ سُلَيْمَانَ ۖ
>   وَمَا كَفَرَ سُلَيْمَانُ وَلَـٰكِنَّ الشَّيَاطِينَ كَفَرُوا
>   يُعَلِّمُونَ النَّاسَ السِّحْرَ وَمَا أُنزِلَ عَلَى الْمَلَكَيْنِ
>   بِبَابِلَ هَارُوتَ وَمَارُوتَ ۚ وَمَا يُعَلِّمَانِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ حَتَّىٰ
>   يَقُولَا إِنَّمَا نَحْنُ فِتْنَةٌ فَلَا تَكْفُرْ ۖ فَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ
>   مِنْهُمَا مَا يُفَرِّقُونَ بِهِ بَيْنَ الْمَرْءِ وَزَوْجِهِ ۚ وَمَا
>   هُم بِضَارِّينَ بِهِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ إِلَّا بِإِذْنِ اللَّـهِ ۚ
>   وَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ مَا يَضُرُّهُمْ وَلَا يَنفَعُهُمْ ۚ وَلَقَدْ عَلِمُوا
>   لَمَنِ اشْتَرَاهُ مَا لَهُ فِي الْآخِرَةِ مِنْ خَلَاقٍ ۚ وَلَبِئْسَ
>   مَا شَرَوْا بِهِ أَنفُسَهُمْ ۚ لَوْ كَانُوا يَعْلَمُونَ ﴿١٠٢
>
> And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the
>   reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils
>   disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the
>   two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not
>   teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve
>   [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which
>   they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm
>   anyone through it except by permission of Allah. And the people learn
>   what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel
>   certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the
>   Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold
>   themselves, if they only knew. (102) (Al-Baqara: 102)

We cannot deny the mentioned issue accordingly. But people ought to pay heed that we cannot always attribute it to the magic, since there could be many other natural items and problems in daily life which are related to that. Of course, I didn’t precisely find if “there is an Islamic way to find out if Sihr is involved?”, however I can term some solution in order to removing its magic (if their problems are really related to the magic). E.g.

- Giving charity
- Reciting the following dua: اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم
- Reciting the following Surahs: al-Falaq, a-Naas. (many times)
- Recting the fowling verses: Al-Qalam:51,52 and Ayatul-Korsi
- It is quoted that Imam Ali (pbuh) said: write and carry the following dua with yourselves (Souce: the book of “Mafatih al Janan, Haj Sheikh Abbas Qomi”
  بِسمِ الله وَ بِالله، بِسمِ الله وَ ما شاءَالله، بِسم الله لاحَولَ ولاقُوّه الا بالله، قالَ موسی ما جِئتُم بِه السِّحرُ اِنَّ اللهَ سَیُبطِلُهُ اِنَّ اللهَ لا یُصلِحُ عَملَ المُفسِدینَ، فَوَقَعَ الحَقُّ و بَطَلَ ما كانُوا یَعمَلونَ فَغُلِبوا هُنالِكَ وَانقَلَبُوا صاغِرینَ

Accordingly, the above-mentioned items consist of some Islamic way to counter Sihr (magic) which hopefully and God willing be helpful for you.

**References:**

[http://www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=259179)

[http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/2:102)

[http://tadabbor.org](http://tadabbor.org/?page=tadabbor&SOID=2&AYID=102)

Answer (score 0):

These kind of questions are really common in the Muslim community. So let's start with the name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful

> We are told in the Qur'an that Prophet Ibraheem, alayhis salam, said,
>   "And when I am ill, it is He Who cures me." [26:80]

The Prophet, sallallahu alayhe wasallam, said: **"There is a remedy for every malady, and when the remedy is applied to the disease it cures it with the permission of Allah, the Exalted and Glorious." (Muslim)** Also, the Prophet, sallallahu alayhe wa sallam, said,

> "Make use of the two remedies: honey and the Qur'an." (Tirmithi)

The use of spiritual forms of healing, such as payers and meditation have become quite popular. This is in part a result of a resurgence in religion and so-called "New Age" beliefs. Major medical centers and health care institutions are even studying the effects of salah on healing. ***For Islamic purposes, the use of specialized prayers (duaa) or Qur'anic verses are known as ruqyah.*** The Prophet, sallallahu alayhe wa sallam, and his companions used this method of healing, as evidenced by many ahadeeth in Bukhari, Muslim, Abu Dawud, Tirmithi and others. Muslims are advised to provide ruqiyah for Muslims and even non-Muslims that are sick. The sick are also able to provide ruqiyah for themselves. Ruqyah is a valuable tool for treating a variety of disorders and diseases. This may include snake or scorpion bite, ***the evil eye (or envy), and psychological problems that Jinn may cause.*** 
**Bukhari has also reported that Suratul Falaq and Suratun Nas (surahs 113 and 114) are also protections against illness and evil.** ***One hadeeth has reported that the Prophet would recite mu'awwidhat (Suratul Falaq and Suratun Nas). He would then blow his breath into his hands and rub his hands over his body, hoping for its blessings. Tirmithi has reported that the Prophet used to seek protection against jinn and the evil eye until Suratul Falaq and Suratun Nas were revealed. After they were revealed, he held to them and discarded everything beside them.***

There are those who believe wearing charms with certain surahs or verses on them are a protection. Others believe that placing these charms on infants will protect them from Jinn and the evil eye or believe that having decorative wall-hangings with Qur'an is a protection. Some may write these verses or surahs on a piece of paper. They then dip the paper into a glass of water and drink the water. ***These actions are not the prescribed actions by the Prophet, sallallahu alayhe wasallam, and may come close to shirk.*** ***Allah and His Messenger have given us directions for using prayer 'whether duaa or ruqyah' and the Qur'an for healing. We must accept these directions and use them accurately while trusting in Allah's Will and Might.***

Comment: You can also include **Ayatul' Kursi** in your dua to get protection from the evil eye or the jinn.

Comment: Thank you! Should find and apply Ruqyah by myself or find some scholar?

Comment: I would recommend you going to your local Sheikh or Imam.

Comment: till then you could read manzil by yourself it has 33 verses from Quran and is widely recited as protection from sihr magic and other problems http://www.slideshare.net/SKHSH/33-quranic-ayats-manzil-arabic-englishversion-sivsya-ayaats

Comment: What you are telling this person to do is no where near enough of what he/she is suppose to do. I know I have been to those raqi's you mention. And most imams don't have this knowledge as this is not taught in their syllabus

Answer (score -3):

Okay I have some experience in this as I am a victim of black magic and do ruqyah. The way you find out if someone is afflicted by black magic is usually by seeing if recitation of Quran or listining to Adhan or doing other acts of worship affects these people.

The reaction to these acts of worship depend on the jinn. A strong jinn will be more resistant.

There are case where a person can be possessed for year with jinn and does not know it until he/she starts increasing in acts of worship such as nafl salat.

see this Youtube link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFdGaru-3dc&t=636s

This happened to me,  when I increased in my acts of worship.

What I feel is the best way is that you undergo an intence ruqyah programme. This way whether it is a strong jinn or weak jinn it will show up. You can increase your worship but there are certain thing you do in ruqyah that specifically attack jinn in a powerful way, so are more effective getting a reaction.

You ruqyah programme must include

1. Drinking at least 1 litre ruqyah water, with added honey and 7 black seeds. To make ruqyah water leave ~5cm air in water bottle, and recite over top Quran verses. At the end of each verse/passage blow and spittle into the water. Verse that you must include are:

Surah Fatiha x11

2:1-10,

2:102 (to treat black magic) x11,

2:255-256,

2:285-286,

3:18-19,

7:117-119 (to treat black magic) x11,

10:81-82 (to treat black magic) x11,

20:65-69 (to treat black magic) x11,

Surah Yaseen 36 (Optional),

Surah Dukhaan 44 (optional),

55:33-35,

72:1-7,

Any other surahs (optional),

112 x3,

113 x3,

114 x3

Another way to get Quran into water is using sheet with Quran printed on them with edible ink. simple put sheets in a big bowl of water and allow the ink to run off. You can buy the whole Quran on only 8 sheets and this would be enough for 80 litre of water. Now they encourage you to get a edible ink printers, you can print Quranic sheets from:

http://ruqyacentre.com/downloads/

2)cover entire body with ruqyah olive oil before sleeping and bathing. Ruqyah oil is made the same way as ruqyah water.

3. A bath with ruqyah water, stay in bath minimum of 30 min, continually pouring water over yourself with pot/jug. You only need to take 2 litre of ruqyah water you made and add it to a full bath. (add 7 sidr leaves, hand full of sea salt to this water, orange blossom water, rose water and apple cider vingar, for the amounts see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqklNcAvCRQ

now that i have edible ink printer I add alot more ruqyah water, I get a very strong reaction with this)

4. read surah Baqara every day. If you cannot read Arabic read the transliteration, I find even if you read it badly it still works.
5. do morning and evening supplications, praising an glorification of Allah.
6. Must offer 5 daily prayer in mosque
7. read tahajjid.
8. recite at least a few hour of Quran daily, surahs such as Yasin, Saffat, surah 44, surah 55, surah jinn, surah 7, surah 2, surah 3 or any other surah but the ones mentioned are known to really attack jinn's
9. There is a special type of ruqyah that is very strong, it involves
   saying the adhan 7 times then saying "Allah humma ag-girnii mi-nan naar" 7 times
   then again saying adhan 7 times then again saying "Allah humma ag-girnii mi-nan naar" 7 times then again saying adhan 7 times then again saying "Allah humma ag-girnii mi-nan naar". Totaling 21 adhan's
10. light inscest in your house that have ruqyah verses mentioned on them, like surah Nas, flaq, aayatul kusi, the more quran you recite on them the stronger they are. In the morning and evening wear a jubba with nothing under it and stand over the inscent stick that is on some kind of dish/ash-tray, let the smoke fill your jubba. Remember morning and eveing is also the time for praiseing and glorifing Allah.
11. Buy a water spray bottle and spray you house with ruqyah water. jinns love corners of rooms; doors (esp door handles); the area next to your head where you sleep, cubards (esp ones that are not really used); rooms that you do not use are there favarite; on shelves and places where people do not go like under the table, etc... do the whole house.
12. do hijjamma, the place for sihr is at the top of your head and jinn. Do this at least once a mounth.
13. recite ruqyah verses for an hour or so, these are the same verses used to make ruqyah water. It is much more effective if you recite these instead of playing them from the internet.
14. one of the most common types of black magic, is ingested. This will not leave the stomach even for decades. You must take senna leaves. Buy senna leaves from net, boil one table spoon in 1-1.5 liters of water until water turns brown and drink it all every day. If you are pregnants take instead milk mixed with honey.
15. do all the adkaars, like reading 3 quls, 3 times for each of the daily prayer and spit-blowing on your hands then all of your body. This on your body.

16)there is a way you can kill the jinn in your dream. do the normal adkaar for sleeping  then recite aayatul kursi 11 times, then sleeping on you right side recite, part of verse 2:148 abudtle till you fall asleep

"ayna maa takoonoo yaati bikumullaahu jamee'aa; innal laaha 'alaa kulli shai'in qadeer"

if you see in your dream the jinn/magician or some images, recite aayatul kursi till it dies. If it tries to run, run after it. Some people are given weapons by Allah like swords in their dreams to fight the jinn/magician.

different people say different instuctions for this see below example in link:

http://www.quran.mu/la-roqya-par-ben-halima-abderraouf-2-of-2.html

17)pray to Allah to make you better alot and abudantly ask for forgiveness.

18. you can attack the jinn, by saying bismillah and pinching part of you body. It hates the chin and top of head being pinched. I also find it hates the fingers, feet, lips, eye lids and many other parts. do this for sometime in the day.
19. Jinns hate black and white itar (perfume), maybe you can couple you activities like reading baqara and smelling black or white itar no perfume at the same time.

I think you main problem will be to make this married couple to do all this and you must do all of it for at least for 21 day to effectively fight the magic. if you get a reaction you must not stop, you may have to adjust the ruqyah with the adapting jinn. But the if you cannot convince your married couple to do all this, at least try recing ruqyah verses for few hours over them, someone recite surah baqara every 3 days in the house (must be recited not played) and see if you get a reaction over a mounth of quicker and do as much of the 19 points. If you get a reaction at least you will know the ansewer to your question.

A person that has no experience of fighting black magic will tell you to make lots of duwahs, obvious things like recite surah Naas, flaq and aayatul kursi,  or go to peer(do not do this)/imam. The imam in my mosques knows nothing about fighting sihr, that because it is not part of their syllabus to learn it. A person with knowlage will tell you pratically what to do, but it is very important that you make lots of duwah and rely on Allah only (and definetly not on taweez/amlet, this is shirk). Relience on Allah is the most important thing.