# How to cancel sihr?

Tags: sihr

Salam alaykum,

My mother is devastated as my youngest sister has been under the sihr her boss and his family has been doing to her to keep her working for them like slaves. They use heavy black magic to keep her under their control and she wouldn't listen to my mother or talk to any family member anymore. They made her completely severe ties with her family and isolated from her family what can we do to take the sihr out of her ? She's not willing to do anything we tell her so she won't accept ruqia or anything else done directly on her since it requires her participation. Can you give us the solution to cancel the sihr even if she's not willing to do so herself? Jazaakum Allah khayran

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Islamic way to counter Sihr (magic)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25831/what-is-the-islamic-way-to-counter-sihr-magic)